# How to empty a Python list without doing list = []?

Tags: python, types

If the `my_list` variable is global, you can't do:

```
my_list = []
```

that just create a new reference in the local scope.

Also, I found disgusting using the `global` keyword, so how can I empty a list using its methods?

Comment: `list` is a type so please don't use that as a variable name.

Comment: Um... You have global variables (which are a chronic problem) and call the `global` keyword "disgusting"?  Wouldn't the presence of global variables be disgusting in the first place?  Why not eliminate all possible need for `global`?  Why work around it?

Comment: @jathanism you're right, very bad choice for the example. I'll fix it in the question.

Comment: @S.Loot it's very common to have global variables in a Python script.

Comment: "it's very common to have global variables"  For you, perhaps.  But I do not ever actually use global variables, so I never have to use a `global` statement.  An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure and a ton of workaround.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
del a[:]
```

or

```
a[:] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following to delete all list items:

```
def emptyit():
    del l[:]
```

Comment: Replacing a practically atomic statement with a function?

Comment: @Beau, it ain't atomic at all. I wouldn't say that 'practically' even comes close.

Comment: @Aaron You're right... Emptying a list is about as unatomic as you can get. I meant semantically atomic, by which I mean it's read as just one statement in the language (delete all of this list).

Comment: @Beau: The function creates a local scope, that seemed pretty obvious that's what he was doing from the question...  He doesn't use the global keyword, and if he wasn't in a function it would just modify the in-scope variable, not the local copy. ....